# Face detection from images or webcam feed

Tags: images, webcam, face-recognition

I am working on a time login system. And I would really love if there was some face recognition that simply read a file from [folder], determined it's name by another folder with lots of images, and then somehow relayed that name. Be it rename the original photo or what.

Anyone got some idea?

Comment: Take a look at [Face recognizing with OpenCV](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/), if you familiar with programming

Comment: picasa by google.  It will scan your whole PC if you let it.

Comment: Are you OK with using web-based services, or do you want to keep everything offline?